# overwriting module config in addons like forms

Tags: c#, episerver, episerver-10

I am developing a solution in EpiServer 10 and I have installed some addons like EpiServer form. Now I want to change the styles of the forms, and the easiest way that comes to my mind is to change the modules.config file for the component.

```
<clientResources>
    <add name="Forms" path="ClientResources/epi-forms/themes/sleek/Forms.css" resourceType="Style" />
</clientResources>
```

But for some addons like EpiServer.Forms, the module.config file is in zip folder and therefore will be erased with each update. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional stylesheet to be loaded when the **Forms** add-on is loaded.

If you add the following to the `module.config` file in your site root...

```
<clientResources>
   <add name="Forms" path="/My/Custom/Style.css" resourceType="Style" />
</clientResources>
```

...it will be loaded when the **Forms** add-on is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/forms/css-styling-and-javascript/) :

You can alter the default styling of a form by directly modifying the CSS file in wwwroot\modules_protected\EPiServer.Forms\0.22.0.9000\ClientResources\ViewMode. You can modify styling rules freely but the following rules apply:

When you adjust the HTML of the view template element, keep the structure (parent-child, block-element relation) and default class names as-is.Keep default CSS classes in the element view template as-is. You can add your own, but do not remove the existing ones.